# How to write C++ code that takes n strings and stores them inside a vector of strings and later prints it

Tags: c++, getline

How to write C++ code that takes *n* strings (can have space between) and store them inside a vector of strings and later prints it?
(Taking the strings inside a vector is necessary.)

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<string> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);
        v.push_back(s);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

This is my code. It is only taking `n - 1` strings instead of taking `n` strings. Then it is printing a new line and then printing the `n - 1` strings.

Comment: *How to write C++ code...*  Firstly, never do `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.  Secondly, never do `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 4):

### Explanation

I see the issue you're encountering. It's related to the interaction between `cin` and `getline`. After using `cin` to read `n`, it captures the number but doesn't remove the newline character from the input buffer. This causes the subsequent `getline` to read an empty string. To bypass this, it's good practice to clear the input buffer right after reading `n`.

### Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');  // Clearing the input buffer

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::string s;
        std::getline(std::cin, s);
        v.push_back(s);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << v[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer ^____^

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

You would get just a newline if you call `getline()` immediately after `cin >> n;`.
To avoid this issue, your would need to consume the newline first.
You can do that by adding this before your *for* loop.

**Code**

```
cin.ignore();
```